# Validator jquery not working with updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi everybody my problem is easy maybe but i'm new using jquery. The next script work good but when i use updatepanel the validation not working and the event clic is firing. I hope somebody could help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("match", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5}$/i.test(value);
    }, "Por favor ingrese un email válido.");

    $("#frmLogin").validate({
        rules: {
            //This section we need to place our custom rule   
            //for the control.  
            <%=inputEmail.UniqueID%>: {
                required: true,
                match: true,
                maxlength: 100
            },
            <%=inputPassword.UniqueID%>: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 10
            },
        },
        messages: {
            //This section we need to place our custom   
            //validation message for each control.  
            <%=inputEmail.UniqueID%>: {
                required: "Ingrese un email",
                match: "Ingrese un email válido",
                maxlength: "Máximo 100 caracteres"
            },
            <%=inputPassword.UniqueID%>: {
                required: "Ingrese un password",
                maxlength: "Máximo 10 caracteres"
            },
        },
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console

Comment: where's the click event?

Comment: i didn't get error and the event click button is in a trigger

Comment: I think you have to add quotation like ' <%=inputEmail.UniqueID%>' in your  field validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(initializeRequestHandler);
> ```

```
    function initializeRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_postBackElement().id == '<%= NameYourButton.ClientID%>' && $("#NameYourForm").valid() !== true) {
         args.set_cancel(true);
     }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update panels don't play nicely with `$(document).ready()`. The problem is that on the partial callback the update panel is replaced, but `$(document).ready()` does not get recalled, so your event bindings are lost. One workaround for this is to resubscribe using the `PageRequestManager`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // bind like normal
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
    // re-bind your events here
});
```

Please note that PageRequestManager is only available if you have an update panel on your page.